# How do I properly use the 'random' function for multiple agents?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have some agents collecting from another agent who they bump into at random after which they move back to their base. As they move back they drop off some material as defined by the random function. Here's some sample code

```
to go
ask searchers 
    [ set energy energy - 1 
      fd 0.0125 
      if random-float 1 < (1 / 50) 
         [ ifelse random 2 = 0 
           [ rt 45 ] 
           [ lt 45 ] 
         ] 
    search
    ]
end

to search
if any? depots in-radius vision with [color = yellow]
[spread
set energy 0] ;; makes them to back to base
end

to spread
if random 10000 = 1 [hatch-rubbish 1 [ set color white 
  set shape "circle"
  set size 0.5]]
 end
```

If I set the visual radius to something enormous so they can always see the depot the number of bits of rubbish works out.

However if I allow them to move around with a radius of 1, the count of rubbish is much higher than 1 in 10,000.

Why would that make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with way off? Is it too big or too small?

Comment: The agents produce the rubbish at a much faster rate than 1 in 10,000.

Comment: Here's some of the relevant code that calls on these tasks in 'to go'    `ask searchers  [
    set energy  energy  - 1   
  fd 0.0125
   if random-float 1 < (1 / 50) 
  [ ifelse random 2 = 0
    [ rt 45 ]
    [ lt 45 ] 
  ]
 search`

Comment: Are the depots patches or another breed of agents?

Comment: They're other agents

Comment: If the radius is huge, then the searchers will always be doing `set energy 0`. Perhaps that's having some effect elsewhere? I still don't think there's anything in the code you've shown us so far that can explain the effect you describe.

Comment: I think we need to see more code, I don't see any problem with these lines.

Comment: One thing that seems to work is if I remove the random-float part of the movement function so the agents only move by fd 1. Would there be any reason for the two calls to 'random' causing a problem?

Comment: Maybe...have you tried  changing `if random-float 1 < (1 / 50)` to  `if (random-float 1 < (1 / 50))` ?

Comment: Hi guys, I've sorted it out. The problem was partly what Seth described in the case when the radius was huge and also my own error in having the two random functions interact. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Make sure to put your fix as an answer!